# Looking for Ubuntu 10.10 driver for GeForce GT 425M GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, sony-vaio, ubuntu-10.10

It came with my Sony VAIO® VPCF133FX/H 16.4" Notebook.

Ubuntu does suggest an NVIDIA driver for me, but when I install it, I cannot boot back in normally. I have to boot into a failsafe mode, then reset graphics setting to default, and reboot again. Right now I am stuck in 800 x 600 mode, but I would like to do better, and take advantage of my 1GB graphics memory :(. Please let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same probleme with my Sony Vaio vpcf13, this problem will be fixed in the next driver that will be released by nvidia, i think that is unfair to treat people using linux like this, if the probleme was on windows they will fixe it in few hours but linux user can wait few weeks.

http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=155218&page=2

Comment: Thanks, well ... MSFT has direction connection to hardware manufacturers; they have agreements, and $$$ is involved. Linux just is not a priority with mere 3M users :(

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on the following forum: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10279164

It is:

> Well, the Nvidia driver that ships
>   with Ubuntu 10.10 only gave me an ever
>   lasting purple screen, so I decided to
>   try the manufacturer driver directly
>   and it worked perfectly! It was
>   actually pretty simple: go to
>   http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us
>   and select your graphics card model. I
>   have a Sony Vaio VPCF1, so I chose
>
> Product Type: GeForce Product Series:
>   GeForce 400M Series Product: GeForce
>   GT 425M Operating System: Linux 32
>   bits Language: English (US)
>
> Download and save the 260.19.29 driver
>   installation script anywhere you find
>   convenient. Then, make it executable
>
> sudo chmod ugo+x
>
> Reboot the computer, choose Ubuntu
>   Safe Mode and boot into root shell.
>   Then, change the runlevel
>
> telinit 3
>
> Run the installation script and follow
>   the instructions on screen. That`s all
>   you need.

Comment: +1 Worked for me, you've solved my problem, thanks Fantomas!